# Spring Hibernate H2 Junit testing - how to load schema on start

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit, h2

I am trying to develop tests for my application (I found out about the tests very late...) and I am stuck and the basic configuration. I have googled through many examples and none of them satisfied me and frankly left me a bit confused.

What I am trying to achieve is to load an import.sql on start of the test (which is a dump file from existing MySQL schema) and load it into H2 database.

**Here is the hibernate config file:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "kamienica.feature" })
public class HibernateTestConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "kamienica" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;"
                + "INIT=CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS kamienica;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE");
        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("");

        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
// this is where I tried to load script the first time:
// properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files", "kamienica.sql");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

Everytime I start a test I get a message that:

> org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseMetadata getTableMetadata INFO:
>   HHH000262: Table not found: apartment

And I get empty/null values when trying to retrieve anything

**I have tried to load sql file in the hibernate config (via hibernate properties) as well as in superclass which all my test classes are planned to extend:**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { HibernateTestConfiguration.class })
public class BaseTest {

    private EmbeddedDatabase db;

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    //second attempt to load sql file
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        db = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().addScript("import.sql").build();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        SessionHolder sessionHolder = (SessionHolder) TransactionSynchronizationManager.unbindResource(sessionFactory);
        SessionFactoryUtils.closeSession(sessionHolder.getSession());
    }

}
```

How can I load sql file and prepare the H2 database to perform the tests?

Comment: I don't know whether this is overkill for you, but in a CI/CD situation you'd use something like Flyway to manage your DB schema for you, and it's perfectly happy to build it up for a test DB.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this spring boot approach will help you. First create a **resources** directory (classpath for springboot)in the src/test directory at the root of your project.
In this directory, you will start placing your fixture SQL data files named say **data.sql** . 
Then, create a application.properties file on the same level (same directory see screenshot). This file should be populated as shown here:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:h2:~/test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
#spring.datasource.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourDB
#spring.datasource.username = root
#spring.datasource.password =

# Hibernate
hibernate.show_sql: true
#hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialec
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
```

Screenshot: 
[image]

Now your tester method.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) 
....
            @Autowired
            private DataSource ds; //your application.properties
            @Autowired
            private WebApplicationContext context;
            private static boolean loadDataFixtures = true;
            private MockMvc mockMvc;
        ....

         @Before
         public void setupMockMvc() {
         mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(context).build();
    }    




        @Before
            public void loadDataFixtures() {
                 if (loadDataFixtures) {
                    ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator(context.getResource("classpath:/data.sql"));
                    DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(populator, ds);
                    loadDataFixtures = false;
                }
            }

@Test
public void yourmethod() {
    assertEquals(3, repository.count()); //example
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without any output or the complete stacktrace, the only I can suggest you is:

1. You aren't showing any `@Test` method. How are you getting that error?
2. Is your file `import.sql` in `src/test/resources` folder? (note the test path)
3. Is your sql script well formated? Have you tried to run once exported? Could you post the part of the sql script wich creates the `apartment` table ?

If all are true, maybe the problem is not about loading the sql but how it's used, or the content of the script, or the name of the tables, etc...

Answer (score 0):

After a long 'investigation' I have concluded that the problem was hidden somewhere in he DBUnit, TestNG setup.

I decided to keep it simple and switched to JUnit tests.

In case others might have similar problems here is the config file that works for me:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "kamienica.feature" })
public class JUnitConfig {

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "kamienica" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:mem:kamienica;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE");

        dataSource.setUsername("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
        return txManager;
    }

}
```

All is needed now is to insert import.sql file in the resources folder.
I also found out that each insert statements must be in one line no matter how long it is, otherwise it won't be loaded.

Finally a simple test class:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { JUnitConfig.class })
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class ApartmentServiceTest extends AbstractServiceTest{

    @Autowired
    ApartmentService service;


    @Test
    public void getList() {
        List<Apartment> list = service.getList();
        System.out.println(list.toString());
        assertEquals(5, list.size());
    }
}
```